# how to test application on Android device

Tags: java, android, testing

I have made application for playing set of Youtube videos in internal youtube player in Android. This application gets array of links and plays it in infinity loop:1,2,3,4,5, then again 1,2,3,4,5, etc. It works on my device, but my friend told me that it is video didn't play on his device. Can you check it?

Link for downloading - http://depositfiles.com/files/vtw1as70u

Code for this:

```
package com.nda.ut;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UTPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private String[] mLinks;
    private int mPosition=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        NetworkUtilities utility=new NetworkUtilities();

        if (utility.getUTLinks("")) {

            mLinks=utility.getLinks();

            if (mLinks!=null) {

                loadPlayer();
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "List is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception with getting of lists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int a, int b, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(a, b, data);

        if (mPosition==mLinks.length-1) {

            mPosition=0;
            loadPlayer();
        }
        else {

            ++mPosition;
            loadPlayer();
        }
    }

    private void loadPlayer() {
        Intent youtube=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mLinks[mPosition]));

        startActivityForResult(youtube, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you may need to do is meet up with your friend, and debug his device to see what the error is or whats causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should do is testing it on the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for Eclipse or any similar IDE that emulates different Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

try to create some AVD with differents versions of Android sdk ( 1.5 , 1.6 ...etc ) , and different resolutions , and then debug your application on those AVDs.